# How to split a comma separated list in javascript, but do not split anything inside quotes with null values

Tags: javascript, split, double-quotes, mirth

I have a comma separated list that could contain blank values, and could contain values wrapped in double-quotes that I do not want to split. I need to create an array using this split so that I can later loop through it.

I've tried using some match regex which works, except it overlooks any null values that I have. I've been trying to use some look ahead regex but I don't think my syntax is working appropriately, as it's returning an array with a length of 1.

This is the match code that most closely shows what I'm going for

```
var s = 'To, Infinity, "And, Beyond",,Buzz Lightyear';
var array = s.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
```

This is the split syntax which is only returning an array length of 1

```
var s = 'To, Infinity, "And, Beyond",,Buzz Lightyear';
var array = s.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

With the match function, I expect the output to be:

```
To
Infinity
And, Beyond

Buzz Lightyear
```

However, my output is actually

```
To
Infinity
And, Beyond
Buzz Lightyear
```

Comment: probably the simplest is to replace quoted commas with a placeholder, then split on comma, then replace each placeholder in a loop. or use a parsing library.

Comment: Look for a library for parsing CSV, it will automate this.

Comment: or you can filter the array to the element that is not empty string.. array.filter(a => a !== '');

Comment: I have updated my answer below !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged mirth in your question, you can use the built in mirth parser. Note that your exact string from your question won't work because there is a space after the comma and before "And, Beyond." If you are going to quote a CSV field, the entire field needs to be quoted (otherwise the quote is seen as part of the value.)

```
var serializer = SerializerFactory.getSerializer('delimited');

var s = 'To,Infinity,"And, Beyond",,Buzz Lightyear';
var split = new XML(serializer.toXML(s));
for each (var col in split.row.children()) {
    logger.info(col.toString());
}
```

Edit: I did not produce an array, since you said you only needed it for looping, which is shown above, but if you still need an array you can do:

```
var arr = [];
for each (var col in split.row.children()) {
    arr.push(col.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per your expectation:

```js
var s = 'To, Infinity, "And, Beyond",,Buzz Lightyear';
var array = s.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This gives a result of `T,o, ,I,n,f,i,n,i,t,y, ,"And, Beyond",B,u,z,z, ,L,i,g,h,t,y,e,a,r`

Comment: Took off my downvote since it does work for the given example, but it does still fail on a number of other valid csv inputs.